# Intermittent slow response and spikes in WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, performance, wcf, wcf-data-services

I've been trying to find the root cause of this issue from the past couple of weeks, but so far no luck.

Currently we are testing our wcf service with a script using powershell. this script behaves like client and passes input xml query to the svc service. In order to replicate high call frequency, we used the same script in 15 different folders, and all make calls to the service at the same time.

so in the span of 15 mins, we might receive 1000 calls and service will process those queries and returns a response xml.

and the average duration of each call is logging at 0.5 sec, But the problem is in those 1000 calls, their might be couple of calls with response time logging at 7 to 10 secs. I have no idea why these spikes are coming. If there are any spikes, then it will not exceeds more than 2.

Our service instance context mode is set as percall, and concurrency is single. I've tried increasing the instance number in my web.config file. that couldn't solving the problem.

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="16"
          maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647"/>
```

could anyone shed some light on this issue.

Comment: have you logged the time difference between the spiked calls with normal ones? It might be IIS unloading the app due to inactivity

Comment: yes, the time difference from the logs is showing around 200 ms to 900 ms (for normal ones), but for this spike it is showing some where around 7 secs. As per the log time entries there is continuous activity in that 15 mins duration, service catered almost 1500 to 2000 calls during that time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [WCF Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098(v=vs.110).aspx)

From your observation that during constant activity, there are instances of response time spikes, i believe it's due to [Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx).